# Truncated singular value decomposition

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, svd

Is it possible to get a "truncated SVD"-regularized solution for L1 norm min errors problem?
$$min\|Ax-b\|_{1}$$
In L2 universe results are derived easily analytically.
I want to formulate a problem for Matlab solver using L1 norm and regularize it using truncated SVD.